# Append Jquery Object into HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append `$(this).parent()` into another div and then remove `$this` element.
I am able to successfully remove `$this` element. But `.append($(this).parent())` seems a wrong approach and not working. I want to make an exact copy into another div before removal of `$this` element.

Reproduced the problem statement:
https://jsfiddle.net/rvgo3Luc/

Comment: `.append($(this).parent().clone())` ??

Comment: @epascarello thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `clone()` to duplicate the element and then append the cloned element.

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){
  console.log($(this).parent());
  // I have to copy this element into say a new div and remove this present element.
  // How to append $(this).parent()
  $("#a").append($(this).parent().clone());
  $(this).remove();
})
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rvgo3Luc/5/)**